# C# Serial port write timeout

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to send serial data every 1ms using VCP (USB Full speed) in C#.

After sending for few minutes, there is error sending the serial data. It is complaining write timeout, and from now I will not be able to send data anymore, the exception is below:

```
System.TimeoutException: The write timed out.
```

I have tried to close and reopen the port, but it still complains about write timeout.

The only way to solve this is to unplug/replug the USB.

May I know how can I solve this write timeout problem in C#? (i guess the USB host controller stuck in the busy state)

My serial port code settings are below:

```
_port.WriteBufferSize = 1024;
_port.ReadBufferSize = 1024;
_port.ReadTimeout = 1;
_port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
_port.WriteTimeout = 16;
_port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
_port.DtrEnable = true;
_port.RtsEnable = true;
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is the screenshot, taken from Eltimata USB analyser, you could see that when in serial portwrite timeout, it has 0 bytes SUCESS sent out.

[image: USB Analyzer using Eltima software]

Comment: Any idea why the timeout happens in the first place?

Comment: It is far too small, less than the thread scheduling quantum of the operating system by a factor of 3.  Don't go below a second.  The ReadTimeout is wrong too but the DataReceived event handler probably keeps you out of trouble.  Beware that it doesn't always do that, everybody forgets to check e.EventType.

Comment: @HansPassant once, i have write timeout, i just send any data thru VCP by clicking on the windows form, it will complain write timeout, there is no way to clear this problem until i unplug the uSB.

Comment: @PaulSasik i believe it happens when the USB host controller is busy, cuz it is FS it works on 1ms time frame either send/write, and since i have schedule it to send every 1 ms, if i receive any data now, it will cause write timeout. and once the 1st exception write timeout throws, i cant send any data anymore, but i could still receive data. even i try to send data by clicking on the form, it throws the exception,

Comment: @HansPassant what should i check about e.EventType? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Increase timeouts, they are designed to give you an error in abnormal conditions. E.g. even if you expect to send/read 1000 times per second use `100 ms` timeout at least to cover case when other side become irresponsible. `1ms` servicing time seems too short I had to use `Thread.Sleep(2)` (in working thread) to be able to service writing. Maybe you should write a manager which will combine multiple writings into a single transmitting?